Is there anywhere I can find a complete list of Elementor setter and getter functions for its free and pro widgets?
I have Elementor Pro and am currently creating a page where there's an Elementor progress bar, an an Elementor heading and several buttons.
I want it so that I can click the buttons and change the heading text and the % value of the progress bar.
pb_strAir and txt_martialArt are CSS id's of the progress bar and the heading respectively. I have this on saved on the Elementor custom code panel and it's attached to the page where the html elements are.
var pbStrAir = document.getElementById('pb_strAir');
var txtMartialArt = document.getElementById('txt_martialArt');

The problem is when I do:
txtMartialArt.textContent = "Earth";

It changes the text, yes, but it deletes all formatting of that element. The same goes for the progress bar.
My question is how do I change the values exactly? Does elementor have any document that lists down how to set/get their elements' attributes? I've been searching for an hour in their documentation (https://developers.elementor.com/docs/widgets/) but couldn't find it. Looked on youtube but all content is focused on using Elementor as a no-code tool so I can't find tutorials where people are trying to change the values programmatically. I've been asking GPT 4.0 for it as well but it doesn't have a clue.
Would appreciate your any ideas/help/suggestions.
Thank you in advance.
As I've described above, I tried using
txtMartialArt.textContent = "Earth";

but it messes up the format and makes the element appear in completely different places than where I placed it. Actually, now I've resorted to just hiding/displaying elements to give the illusion of it changing but I quickly discovered I can't proceed this way because I also plan to add animations to the elements and that would make it a nightmare to do if there are a lot of hidden elements.
